# Unable to get the function working, program always crashes after prompt

Tags: c, function

Since in C its seems to be impossible to use switch with chars(only integers) im trying to make a simple prompt using the if function, the problem is after scanf point the program always crashes at this points `puts("Confirmas que quieres borrar[s\\n]")` or "are you sure you wanna erase it?".

```
void borrar_peliculas(struct videoclub peliculas[30],int p) {
    char titulo_pelicula[30], resp_eliminar;
    int k = 0;

    puts("\a\nBorrador de peliculas");

    puts("\nDime el titulo de la pelicula a ser borrada\n");
    scanf("%30s", titulo_pelicula);

    for (k = 0;k < p ;k++) {

        if (strcmp(peliculas[k].nombre,titulo_pelicula) ==0 ) {

            puts("\nConfirmas que quieres borrar[s\\n]\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", resp_eliminar);

            if(resp_eliminar=='s') {

                peliculas[k].id = 0;
                strcpy(peliculas[k].nombre," ");
                strcpy(peliculas[k].categoria," ");
                strcpy(peliculas[k].nom_actor," ");
                strcpy(peliculas[k].ape_actor," ");
                peliculas[k].nota = 0;

                break;

            }

            if(resp_eliminar=='n') {
                puts("\a\nSaliendo\n");
                break;
            }

        } else {
            puts("\nNo encontrado\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible to `switch` on a `char`.  How were you trying to do it before?

Comment: Please sort your indentation out before expecting other people to read your code.

Comment: i used case 's' or case 'n':

Comment: `fflush()` is for output streams, its use on input streams is undefined

Comment: So how i deal with a garbage data in buffers?

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` takes a pointer. If you replace `scanf("%c", resp_eliminar);` with `scanf("%c", &resp_eliminar);` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You have one very big error here.  The `scanf` function requires a *pointer* to the variable that will store the input.  Your current program invokes undefined behavior.

Instead of this:

```
scanf("%c", resp_eliminar);
```

Do this:

```
scanf("%c", &resp_eliminar);
```

Comment: Yeah its that...a guy told me to never put a & in a Char or String...thanks anyway!

Comment: That guy meant that when scanning a string(`%s`) using `scanf` into array of characters, you don't need `&` before the variable name.